# From a spring mvc controller action, how do I get access to request/response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-response-codes

My action looks like:

```
public String add() {

   return "/WEB-INF/views/add.jsp";
}
```

In this case I need access to a posted form field parameter. Once I receive the posted parameter value, I will save it to the db and then return an http response code of 200 if there are no errors. If an error has occured, I will return HTTP 500 response code.

How can I set the http response code in the return (instead of the view unless I can do both?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is a `@RequestMapping`-annoted controller, then just declare the form field as a parameter:

```
public String add(String myformFieldName) {
```

To return an explicit status code on the response, then declare the response and set it:

```
public String add(String myformFieldName, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
   httpResponse.setStatus(...); 
}
```

Comment: Does spring inject the parameters, just unclear how just adding the parameters like HttpServletResponse/Request get injected into my action?

Comment: As always with Spring, it relies on a hefty amount of magic to auto-inject this for you.